# nth root of unity in $\mathbb{Q}_p $

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $n\in \mathbb N,$  and $p$ be a prime number. Let $\zeta_n$ be a nth root of unity in $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}.$

> Under what conditions we have $\zeta_n\in\mathbb Q_p$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @IgorRivin I think that $n$ must verify $n\equiv 1\pmod p$

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: I really am puzzled why this would be closed. It is way better than the majority of the questions which get asked here and stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if an equation has a root mod $p,$ the solution can be "lifted" to $\mathbb{Q}_p.$ So, if there is an $n$-th root mod $p$ you are good.